# how can i make my calculation using math.sqrt right?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, math, addition

I just want to get the square root of total2 .. but it won't appear in the selected box .. 
here is the javascript codes.
i'll comment the html codes.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var q1 = document.getElementById("qinput1").value;
  var q2 = document.getElementById("qinput2").value;
  var q3 = document.getElementById("qinput3").value;
  var total = parseInt(q1) + parseInt(q2) + parseInt(q3);

  document.getElementById("ainput3").value=total;

  var a1 = document.getElementById("ainput1").value;
  var a2 = document.getElementById("ainput2").value;
  //from the total we got, lets assign it a variable for further calculation
  var a3 = document.getElementById("ainput3").value=total;
  var total2 = parseInt(a1)*parseInt(a2)/ parseInt(a3);
  document.getElementById("ansA").value = total2;

  var total3 = math.sqrt(parseInt(total2));
  document.getElementById("sqaureD").value = total3;
}

function myShapes() {
  document.getElementById('squareA').style.display = 
    document.getElementById('shapes').value == 'Square' ? 'block' : 'none'
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="fcalculation"> 
  <fieldset> 
    <legend>Calculation of qu</legend> 
    <label><i>Ultimate bearing capacity</i> <b>(qu) = </b></label> 
    <input id="qinput1" type="text" placeholder="c'NcFcsFcdFci"/> + 
    <input id="qinput2" type="text" placeholder="qNqFqsFqdFqi"/> + 
    <input id="qinput3" type="text" placeholder="½βγNFγsFγdFγi"/> 
  </fieldset> 
</form>
```

it seems that the calculation part at the very end is not working. sorry its my first time to code.

Comment: <form action="" id="fcalculation">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Calculation of qu</legend>
                <label ><i>Ultimate bearing capacity</i> <b>(qu) = </b></label>
                <input id="qinput1" type="text" placeholder="c'NcFcsFcdFci"/> +
                <input id="qinput2" type="text" placeholder="qNqFqsFqdFqi"/> +
                <input id="qinput3" type="text" placeholder="½βγNFγsFγdFγi"/>
            </fieldset> 
            <fieldset>

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Classname is `Math` not `math`

Try replacing

```
var total3 = math.sqrt(parseInt(total2,10));
```

with

```
var total3 = Math.sqrt(parseInt(total2,10));
```

Also, looking at your markup, there are no fields with id `ainput1`, `ainput2` and `ainput3`.

Comment: please add radix to [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: @NinaScholz made the changes, usually it is defaulted to 10

Comment: *"If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal) or 10 (decimal).  Exactly which radix is chosen is implementation-dependent.  ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used, but not all browsers support this yet.  For this reason always specify a radix when using parseInt."*